# using binomial probabilities

Tags: probability

The probability  of Jack hitting a target is $1/4$.
How many times must he fire so that the probability of hitting the target at least once is greater than $2/3$?

using the formula $(nCx)(p^x)((p')^{n-x})$

I identified $p=1/4$, $p'=3/4$, $x=?$, $n=?$

in order to solve this que, I have to solve $x$ but i couldn't identified it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Jack fires $n$ times and $X$ being the number of times Jack hits the target, you have that
$$P(X \geq 1) = 1 - P(X=0) = 1 - \binom{n}{0}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^0 \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n = 1 - \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n.$$
Now, find $n$ so that the expression above is greater than $\frac{2}{3}$.